# How can I run hudson under tomcat as a non-root user?

Tags: tomcat, root, hudson

Currently my tomcat is running as root because it does bind to port 80.

I do want to run hudson as a non-root user inside tomcat. How do I do this?

I'm looking for a solution that would not require me to add an apache proxy over tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, only root can bind to ports le 1024. probably there's no mechanism of dropping privs in java/jvm after binding to superuser ports otherwise this would be done by now in tomcat. what i and others did was to keep tomcat listening on a non-privileged port and forward port 80 traffic to that port with a firewall rule.

Comment: i wasn't exactly right. you may use jsvc to run the workers as a non privileged user. check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/setup.html#Unix_daemon

Answer (score 1):

You can forward port 80 to 8080 or any other using iptables, like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d second_ip --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

This is a more generic one, but if you have only one IP remove the destination IP (-d second_ip).